# Email Services : Short Email Alias - Salesforce

Tags: email

Is there any way so that we can create alias name for email services as it is a 100 char length email.

Is there any way to shorten it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not on the salesforce.com side. Those characters are used by the system to identify which class/org is going to handle the request, and are automatically created, and managed, by the Salesforce platform. You could make an alias on your mail server, assuming it supports setting forwarding aliases.